# Gearman callback with nested jobs

Tags: gearman

I have a gearman job that runs and itself executes more jobs when in turn may execute more jobs. I would like some kind of callback when all nested jobs have completed. I can easily do this, but my implementations would tie up workers (spin until children are complete) which I do not want to do.

Is there a workaround? There is no concept of "groups" in Gearman AFAIK, so I can't add jobs to a group and have something fire once that group has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, there's nothing built-in to Gearman to handle this. If you don't want to tie up a worker (and letting that worker add tasks and track their completion for you), you'll have to do out-of-band status tracking.

A way to do this is to keep a group identifier in memcached, and increment the number of finished subtasks when a task finishes, and increment the number of total tasks when you add a new one for the same group. You can then poll memcached to see the current state of execution (tasks finished vs tasks total).

Comment: This is roughly what I ended up doing. Works fine, but difficult to debug at times.